# Did hdmi ever not support audio?

Tags: audio, sound

My professor was going through slides and said “Oops, that should say hdmi supported. I wrote these slides when HDMI didn’t support sound.” Is this true? I can’t find anything saying that HDMI didn’t support sound at one point

Comment: No, he probably just isn’t a tech person.

Comment: I do not believe this should be closed, HDMI, and the audio portion of that is certainly a protocol used in many professional applications. I also believe that this would be a searchable question, providing reference for future queries.

Comment: HDMI is a consumer protocol. The question is also a hardware question and nothing to do with sound design.

Comment: @Timinycricket It's funny that you say that. I was quite sure his statement was incorrect, but the class is called computing concepts. One of those burner plate courses that you can't get out of. I'm glad to see I've put my money to good use. smh...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a true expert in this, but will try to answer this using Wiki articles.
*The authenticity of this answer is directly related on what trust you place in the articles.*

> Did hdmi ever not support audio?

---

**TL&DR;**

From Wiki information, in may be concluded that `HDMI version 1.0`, using standard `EIA/CEA-861-B`, which in turns uses `CEA EDID Timing Extension data format - Version 3`, did include various audio channels/codec's.

**Unless your Proffessor is mentioning HDMI draft versions prior to 1.0, the statement is not correct.**

---

**1) the beginning**

So we are looking for the very beginning of the HDMI standard, possibly even 1.0.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI

"*HDMI uses the Consumer Electronics Association/Electronic Industries Alliance 861 standards. HDMI 1.0 to HDMI 1.2a uses the EIA/CEA-861-B video standard*"

**2) Digging into 861-B**

Great, so we know that the first HDMI standards used this "861-B" thing... lets dig in.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Display_Identification_Data#CEA-861-E

"*The CEA EDID Timing Extension was first introduced in EIA/CEA-861, and has since been updated several times, most notably with the −861B revision (which was version 3 of the extension, adding Short Video Descriptors and advanced audio capability/configuration information)*"

**3) Don't you love technical details**

Same source as 2, will list you some protocol details, and the various audio codec's which can be used with this standard.

[snip]

```
'''Audio Data Blocks''' contain one or more 3-byte Short Audio Descriptors (SADs).  Each SAD
    details audio format, channel number, and bitrate/resolution capabilities of the display as
    follows:
    SAD Byte 1 (format and number of channels):
       bit 7: Reserved (0)
       bit 6..3: Audio format code
         1 = Linear Pulse Code Modulation (LPCM)
         2 = AC-3
         3 = MPEG1 (Layers 1 and 2)
         4 = MP3
         5 = MPEG2
         6 = AAC
         7 = DTS
         8 = ATRAC
         0, 15: Reserved 
         9 = One-bit audio aka SACD
        10 = DD+
        11 = DTS-HD
        12 = MLP/Dolby TrueHD
        13 = DST Audio
        14 = Microsoft WMA Pro
       bit 2..0: number of channels minus 1  (i.e. 000 = 1 channel; 001 = 2 channels; 111 =
                 8 channels)

    SAD Byte 2 (sampling frequencies supported):
       bit 7: Reserved (0)
       bit 6: 192kHz
       bit 5: 176kHz
       bit 4: 96kHz
       bit 3: 88kHz
       bit 2: 48kHz
       bit 1: 44kHz
       bit 0: 32kHz

    SAD Byte 3 (bitrate):
      For LPCM, bits 7:3 are reserved and the remaining bits define bit depth
       bit 2: 24 bit
       bit 1: 20 bit
       bit 0: 16 bit
    For all other sound formats, bits 7..0 designate the maximum supported bitrate divided by 
    8 kbit/s.
```

[/snip]

**CONCLUSION**

From Wiki information, in may be concluded that `HDMI version 1.0`, using standard `EIA/CEA-861-B`, which in turns uses `CEA EDID Timing Extension data format - Version 3`, did include various audio channels/codec's.

**Unless your Proffessor is mentioning HDMI draft versions prior to 1.0, the statement is not correct.**

Comment: Why a negative vote ? Care to explain that so I can learn from it ?

Comment: You're presenting rehashed wiki articles as an answer to a question that has nothing to do with sound design. No independent research other than wikipedia references.

Comment: @Mark, thank you for your opinion. Noted and will be taken into account next time. I do however question if "referencing Wiki articles" is a criteria for down-voting. I believe the answer is still very relevant to the question asked. Whether or not the question is valid is a different subject and I do have a different opinion on this. For now I will leave this answer up.